# Sorting A list based on another list using qsort

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I have a list int A[size] and and a list maxA[size] that should contain indexes to A[size] sorted by the values of A. Basically A[maxA[0]] should be the element of the biggest int in A, and maxA[0] its index.

Here is my compare Function:

```
int compareA(const void *a,const void *b){
    return A[*(TYPE *)b] - A[*(TYPE *)a]; 
}
```

And I call it with

```
qsort(maxA,SIZE_L,sizeof(int),compareA);
```

I have a loop that increase values of a element by a random possitive number and when A[i] > L (L is defined by a list of endings and it is kind of random) then :

```
A[maxA[i]] = INT_MIN;
```

and then stop increasing it
After some time it stop working. Here is my output:

```
INDEX VALUE
1  320 
2  207 
8  -437 
3  -681 
4  -960 
6  -1638 
5  -2928 
9  -7395 
7  -19272 
0  -2147483648
Removed: 1
6  -1560 500                 
5  -2684 1000                
9  -7140 1066                
7  -18396 1168               
1  -2147483648 
0  -2147483648 
2  276
3  0 
8  -418 
4  -864
```

Why do I get this random behavior;

Comment: Instead of describing your code ("I have a list ..."), try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology.  You have two arrays.  A list has connotations of “linked list", which is quite different.

Comment: You might want to look up `qsort_r()`, but beware: it is non-standard and different platforms implement different (wholly incompatible) interfaces to the same name.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive. And http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/. And http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: The output shows "removed: 1", was a value removed from A[] and maxA[] ? If so, and you call qsort again, are you still using SIZE_L as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is more or less impossible, unless you do some ugly hacking. `qsort` simply does not support this.

I'd write a custom sorting function. Choose a sorting algorithm and search the web for some code. Bubble sort, selection sort and insertion sort are fairly easy to implement. If you want more performance for the general case you can look at quick sort, merge sort or heap sort. But if you just want this for integer arrays, you could have a look at bucket sort. What you do then is a simple modification to the code you found.

For instance, change:

```
void sort(int * arr, size_t size)
{
    ...
    if([i]<arr[i+1]) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[i+1])
    }
    ...
}
```

to

```
void sort(int * arr, size_t size, int * arr2, size_t size2)
{
    ...
    if(arr[i]<arr[i+1]) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[i+1])
        swap(arr2[i], arr2[i+1])
    }
    ...
}
```

Just simply add a second array and size to the argument list and then perform the same changes on both arrays.

And as Jonathan Leffler pointed out, be careful of how you use the words `list` and `array`. A list is usually a linked list. They are a bit trickier to sort, but it is quite easy to find code examples for that too if that's what you want. Since you try to solve this with `qsort` I assume you're talking about arrays.

If you want to use the existing `qsort` I think the best way would be to first create an array of structs. Something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int A;
    int maxA;
} comboElement;

...
comboElement mergedList[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    mergedList[i].A = A[i];
    mergedList[i].maxA = maxA[i];
}

qsort(mergedList, size, sizeof(mergedList[0]),compareMergedList);
```

Of course, you have to rewrite your compare function. Side not here: When you're invoking `qsort`, do not use `sizeof <type>`. Use `sizeof <first element in list>` instead. The reason is that if you change type in the future, you may forget to change all instances.